# Raspberry Pi has no GPIO Output

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, output, voltage

my raspberry pi 3B+ hast the latest Buster Update(Installed 23.03.2020). When I measure the GPIO output I get with at the 5V pin around 0.025V of output and at the 3V pin the multimeter says 0V. I tested the pins with the gpiotest from the pigpio library. The test says that every pin is alright. I already tried reinstalling the operating system. But I have still no output. Does anyone know why it has no output or how I could fix it?
Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Which pins are you testing with the multimeter? https://pinout.xyz Are you sure your multimeter works? Don't short any pins or you may kill your pi.

Comment: I tested the two 5V pins and the two 3V pins. I also tested with a simple python script the other gpios and no my multimeter is definitly not broken and I also tested it with a LED.

Comment: If I read correctly, the Pi works otherwise? So it boots fine?

Comment: To test a voltage you would need to test between GND and 5V or GND and 3V.

Comment: it is possible that you are using the multimeter incorrectly .... please describe in detail what you did to measure the pin voltage

Comment: The 3.3V & 5V pins are **NOT** GPIO. Poking at the expansion header with multimeter is dangerous - momentarily touching both  3.3V & 5V pins will instantaneously kill the Pi. Even with >55 years experience I wouldn't do this - attach Du-Pont connectors to the header.

Comment: I used the multimeter correctly but I still tested the 3.3V and the 5V  pin with a LED that has worked before. I also tested the GPIO pins with the LED. Before you ask I tested with several LED they all didn't worked. I also don' really believe that the Pi is physically damaged because it stopped working from one to the next day without doing anything with it.